# How can I make Svelte's DraggableDraw component not open at startup?

Tags: javascript, frontend, draggable, svelte, svelte-component

I am currently using this Svelte component and I would like to know if anyone knows how the startup can be changed so that it does not open after loading, so that it only opens when pressing a button.

This is the [link](https://github.com/pupubird/svelte-draggable-draw) for the component I am referring to and [this](https://svelte.dev/repl/a76f1b9d987c43f1ac457efb189d5d0d) is the example in Svelte REPL.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The answer *should* be to change `let visible = true` to `let visible = false`. That fails because the component expects `visible` to be true initially. That seems like a bug, and you should probably raise it on the component's issue tracker.

Short of that, you can wrap the whole lot in `{#if visible}`:

```html
{#if visible}
  <DraggableDraw {maxVH} {minVH}>
    <!-- ... -->
  </DraggableDraw>
{/if}
```

But that may not have the intended behaviour, since the component will now be recreated every time `visible` becomes true.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I had tried changing the variable `let visible = false` , but it didn't work I didn't know what to do. I have listened to you and have reported the problem to the creator of the component.